# Caret position in Word 2007 addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, vsto, word-addins

I want to display a form at the current caret position in Microsoft word 2007 addin. I can easily find the mouse Cursor position using [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(v=vs.90).aspx) class. However I couldn't find a way to get the position of Caret. Is there a way to find the position in [Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model provides the [Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834587(v=office.15).aspx) property which provides the cursor position information. You just need to pass the [WdInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213848(v=office.12).aspx) enum value to get the required data.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to represent the information returned from wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage as Point (X,Y). Do you know if there is a way to do this?